# SAML - How to Correctly Sign both Response(Message) and Assertion

Tags: java, saml, onelogin, opensaml

I'm using Java8, and I tried both OpenSAML(v3) and OneLogin but none of them worked.

- Validation Check Tool : https://samltool.io/
- Signing Assertion Only : Valid
- Signing Response Only : Valid
- Signing Both : Response Signature Invalid

Using [this site](https://www.samltool.com/sign_response.php) I tried

- Sign Both : Valid
- Sign Assertion > Copy then Sign Response : Valid
- Sign Assertion via Code > Sign Response : Response Signature Invalid

Response Signature Inavlid Message looks like this *"XMLJS0013: Cryptographic error: Invalid digest for uri '$REFERENCE_URI'. Calculated digest is $CALCULATED_DIGESTVALUE but the xml to validate supplies digest $MY_DIGESTVALUE"*

When I manually replace $MY_DIGESTVALUE with $CALCULATED_DIGESTVALUE, the error message changes to *"The calculated signature does not match the signature of the message."*

```java
/* Methods */
// For OneLogin
private Object stringTOobject(String samlStr) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(samlStr.getBytes("UTF-8")));  
    Element samlElement = document.getDocumentElement();
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = XMLObjectProviderRegistrySupport.getUnmarshallerFactory().getUnmarshaller(samlElement);
    return unmarshaller.unmarshall(samlElement);
}
// For OpenSAML
private <T> T createObject(Class<T> clazz) throws Exception {
    QName defaultElementName = (QName) clazz.getDeclaredField("DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME").get(null);
    Object object = SAMLutil.getSAMLBuilder().getBuilder(defaultElementName).buildObject(defaultElementName);
    return clazz.cast(object);
}
private KeyInfo getKeyInfo(BasicX509Credential basicCredential, HashMap reqMap) throws Exception {
    KeyInfo result = null;
    KeyName keyName = createObject(KeyName.class);
    keyName.setValue($KeyID);
    X509KeyInfoGeneratorFactory kiFactory = new X509KeyInfoGeneratorFactory();
    kiFactory.setEmitEntityCertificate(true);
    result = kiFactory.newInstance().generate(basicCredential);
    result.getKeyNames().add(keyName);
    // To remove linebreaks in Certificate
    result.getX509Datas().get(0).getX509Certificates().get(0).setValue($X509CertificateString);
    return result;
}
private Signature getSig(HashMap reqMap) throws Exception {
    Signature result = createObject(Signature.class);
    BasicX509Credential basicCredential = getBasicX509Credential($X509CertificateString);
    basicCredential.setPrivateKey($PrivateKey);
    KeyInfo keyInfo = getKeyInfo(basicCredential, reqMap);
    result.setKeyInfo(keyInfo);
    result.setCanonicalizationAlgorithm(SignatureConstants.ALGO_ID_C14N_EXCL_OMIT_COMMENTS);
    result.setSignatureAlgorithm(SignatureConstants.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_RSA_SHA1);
    result.setSigningCredential(basicCredential);
    return result;
}

/* OneLogin */
// 1. Sign Assertion > Turn signed string back to Assertion
AssertionMarshaller aMarshaller = new AssertionMarshaller();
String astStr = Util.addSign(aMarshaller.marshall(assertion), privateKey, cert, Constants.RSA_SHA1);
assertion = (Assertion) stringTOobject(astStr);
// 2. Add Assertion into Response
response.getAssertions().add(assertion);
// 3. Sign Response > Turn signed string back to Response
ResponseMarshaller marshaller = new ResponseMarshaller();
String resStr = Util.addSign(marshaller.marshall(response), privateKey, cert, Constants.RSA_SHA1);
response = (Response) stringTOobject(resStr);
// 4. To XMLString
String samlStr = SerializeSupport.nodeToString(marshaller.marshall(response));

/* OpenSAML */
// 1. Sign Assertion
Signature signature = getSig(reqMap);
assertion.setSignature(signature);
((SAMLObjectContentReference)signature.getContentReferences().get(0)).setDigestAlgorithm(SignatureConstants.ALGO_ID_DIGEST_SHA1);
AssertionMarshaller aMarshaller = new AssertionMarshaller();
aMarshaller.marshall(assertion);
Signer.signObject(signature);
// 2. Add Assertion into Response
response.getAssertions().add(assertion);
// 3. Sign Response
Signature signature = getSig(reqMap);
response.setSignature(signature);
((SAMLObjectContentReference)signature.getContentReferences().get(0)).setDigestAlgorithm(SignatureConstants.ALGO_ID_DIGEST_SHA1);
ResponseMarshaller marshaller = new ResponseMarshaller();
marshaller.marshall(response);
Signer.signObject(signature);
// 4. To XMLString
String samlStr = SerializeSupport.nodeToString(marshaller.marshall(response));
```

What am I missing?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Signer.signObject(signature); why are you signing the signature here?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. I saw some code uses "Signer.signObject(signature)" and some uses "Signer.signObject(assertion)". Using the former one, it passes the validation check. Should I use signObject(assertion) / signObject(response) though?

Comment: you should sign the assertion and response if the idp is expecting them signed.

Comment: Oh I am the IDP side by the way. I'll try signObject(assertion) and signObject(response)!

Comment: I tried changing Signer.signObject(signature) to signObject(response); then I get the error message "The method signObject(Signature) in the type Signer is not applicable for the arguments (Response)". So Signer.signObject(signature) is the correct way I guess.

Comment: So... It's not common to sign both **unless** you are encrypting the entire assertion, signing it, then signing the wrapping response. Has your Service Provider said that they require both to be signed? Because if not, then I would suggest signing the overall response, and leave it at that.

Comment: Yeah the first time I tried just signing assertion only cuz the sp spec requires the signed assertion. It kinda worked that I could sign in /w signed assertion but the problem is that I cannot get to the beginning service. SP said that the beginning service might need signed response. So I'm trying to sign both now. [Excel/Word/Teams etc > Azure AD (SP) > IDP > Azure AD (SP) > should go back to the service(Excel/Word/Teams) but it has lost the appid somewhere that it goes to office.com page] Oh I should encrypt assertion > sign assertion > sign response you mean? I'll try that!

Comment: I tried encrypting the assertion using this tool (https://www.samltool.com/encrypt.php) RSA_1_5 & AES128_CBC then I realized that the "saml:Assertion" is changed to "saml:AssertionEncrypted". When I use the tool's(https://www.samltool.com/sign_response.php) "Sign Message and Assertion" though, the Assertion is still "saml:Assertion". Am I misunderstanding what your point? (I still tried signing the assertion anyway, but it doesn't spit any result; I guess it can only take raw assertion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it was the line break in assertion that was making this whole issue.
I just replaced the special characters and it magically works so well now.. wow....
The tones of time for nothing... wow.....

```
astStr = astStr.replace("&#13;", "").replace("&#xD;", "");
```